# XSLT to transform an xml with repeated sibblings to a flat file

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0, xslcompiledtransform

I have an xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <GetSavedReportResponse>
  <ResponseType>Success</ResponseType>
  <FileModifiedDateTime>2012-01-03T17:05:04</FileModifiedDateTime>
  <FileSizeBytes>7816</FileSizeBytes>
  <FileDataFormat>XML</FileDataFormat>
  <FileData>
    <Zthes>
      <term>
        <termId>49555</termId>
        <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
        <termName>Active Personnel</termName>
        <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
        <termVocabulary>Global People Status</termVocabulary>
        <termCategory>PDA</termCategory>
        <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
        <termCategory>GLB</termCategory>
        <relation weight="100">
          <termId>49556</termId>
          <relationType>EQ</relationType>
          <termName>term name</termName>
          <termVocabulary>term vocabulary</termVocabulary>
        </relation>
        <relation weight="100">
          <termId>49557</termId>
          <relationType>BT</relationType>
          <termName>General Active Personnel</termName>
          <termVocabulary>People Status Global Updated</termVocabulary>
        </relation>
      </term>
      <term>
        <termId>49556</termId>
        <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
        <termName>Leave of Absence Personnel</termName>
        <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
        <termCategory>GLB</termCategory>
        <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
        <relation weight="100">
          <relationType>BT</relationType>
          <termId>49554</termId>
          <termName>General Non-Active Personnel</termName>
          <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
        </relation>
      </term>
    </Zthes>
  </FileData>
</GetSavedReportResponse>
```

I need to transform it into a flat file. For that, I have writen the following xsl

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:template match="Zthes">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="term">
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>GL</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="termCategory">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="termVocabulary">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="relation/termVocabulary">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so, the output should be

"HDR";"Text";"20120112045620";"F"
"GL";"PDA";"People Status Global";"term vocabulary"
"GL";"PDA";"People Status Global";"People Status Global Updated"
"GL";"PDA";"Global People Status";"term vocabulary"
"GL";"PDA";"Global People Status";"People Status Global Updated"
"GL";"PDI";"People Status Global";"term vocabulary"
"GL";"PDI";"People Status Global";"People Status Global Updated"
"GL";"PDI";"Global People Status";"term vocabulary"
"GL";"PDI";"Global People Status";"People Status Global Updated"
"GL";"GLB";"People Status Global";"term vocabulary"
"GL";"GLB";"People Status Global";"People Status Global Updated"
"GL";"GLB";"Global People Status";"term vocabulary"
"GL";"GLB";"Global People Status";"People Status Global Updated"
"FTR";12

with my xsl I am gettin single row:
"GL";"PDAPDIGLB";"People Status GlobalGlobal People Status";"term vocabularyPeople Status Global Updated"

And a header row :
"HDR";"PIGLSSTD";"20120112045620";"F":
should be appended at the start, along with a footer row 
    "FTR";
    
at the bottom.

Comment: You are mixing for-each and template. Pick one approach and stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You want something like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:defaults>
   <termCat/>
   <termVocab/>
 </my:defaults>

 <xsl:variable name="vDefaults" select="document('')/*/my:defaults"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vQ">"</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="term">
   <xsl:variable name="vTerm" select="."/>

   <xsl:variable name="vRow1" select="'&#xA;&quot;GL&quot;;'"/>

     <xsl:for-each select=
      "termCategory
      |
       $vDefaults/termCat[not($vTerm/termCategory)]">
       <xsl:variable name="vRow2" select=
           "concat($vRow1, $vQ, ., $vQ, ';')"/>

       <xsl:for-each select=
        "$vTerm/termVocabulary
        |
         $vDefaults/termCat[not($vTerm/termVocabulary)]
        ">
         <xsl:variable name="vRow3" select=
           "concat($vRow2, $vQ, ., $vQ, ';')"/>

        <xsl:for-each select=
         "$vTerm/relation/termVocabulary
         |
          $vDefaults/termCat[not($vTerm/relation/termVocabulary)]
         ">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($vRow3, $vQ, ., $vQ, ';')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<GetSavedReportResponse>
    <ResponseType>Success</ResponseType>
    <FileModifiedDateTime>2012-01-03T17:05:04</FileModifiedDateTime>
    <FileSizeBytes>7816</FileSizeBytes>
    <FileDataFormat>XML</FileDataFormat>
    <FileData>
        <Zthes>
            <term>
                <termId>49555</termId>
                <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
                <termName>Active Personnel</termName>
                <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
                <termVocabulary>Global People Status</termVocabulary>
                <termCategory>PDA</termCategory>
                <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
                <termCategory>GLB</termCategory>
                <relation weight="100">
                    <termId>49556</termId>
                    <relationType>EQ</relationType>
                    <termName>term name</termName>
                    <termVocabulary>term vocabulary</termVocabulary>
                </relation>
                <relation weight="100">
                    <termId>49557</termId>
                    <relationType>BT</relationType>
                    <termName>General Active Personnel</termName>
                    <termVocabulary>People Status Global Updated</termVocabulary>
                </relation>
            </term>
            <term>
                <termId>49556</termId>
                <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
                <termName>Leave of Absence Personnel</termName>
                <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
                <termCategory>GLB</termCategory>
                <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
                <relation weight="100">
                    <relationType>BT</relationType>
                    <termId>49554</termId>
                    <termName>General Non-Active Personnel</termName>
                    <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
                </relation>
            </term>
        </Zthes>
    </FileData>
</GetSavedReportResponse>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
"GL";"PDA";"People Status Global";"term vocabulary";
"GL";"PDA";"People Status Global";"People Status Global Updated";
"GL";"PDA";"Global People Status";"term vocabulary";
"GL";"PDA";"Global People Status";"People Status Global Updated";
"GL";"PDI";"People Status Global";"term vocabulary";
"GL";"PDI";"People Status Global";"People Status Global Updated";
"GL";"PDI";"Global People Status";"term vocabulary";
"GL";"PDI";"Global People Status";"People Status Global Updated";
"GL";"GLB";"People Status Global";"term vocabulary";
"GL";"GLB";"People Status Global";"People Status Global Updated";
"GL";"GLB";"Global People Status";"term vocabulary";
"GL";"GLB";"Global People Status";"People Status Global Updated";
"GL";"GLB";"People Status Global";"People Status Global";
"GL";"PDI";"People Status Global";"People Status Global";
```

**Explanation**: You want to do output only when a complete line has been formed -- not before that.

**Update**: The OP works in an environment, where the `document()` function is disabled. He also wants a header and a footer.

In this case a slightly modified transformation can be used (using the `exslt:node-set()` extension function) now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vrtfDefaults">
       <termCat/>
       <termVocab/>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="vDefaults" select=
      "ext:node-set($vrtfDefaults)"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vQ">"</xsl:variable>

     <xsl:template match="Zthes">
      <xsl:text>HDR";"PIGLSSTD";"20120112045620";"F":</xsl:text>

        <xsl:apply-templates/>

      <xsl:text>&#xA;FTR</xsl:text>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="term">
       <xsl:variable name="vTerm" select="."/>

       <xsl:variable name="vRow1" select="'&#xA;&quot;GL&quot;;'"/>

         <xsl:for-each select=
          "termCategory
          |
           $vDefaults/termCat[not($vTerm/termCategory)]">
           <xsl:variable name="vRow2" select=
               "concat($vRow1, $vQ, ., $vQ, ';')"/>

           <xsl:for-each select=
            "$vTerm/termVocabulary
            |
             $vDefaults/termCat[not($vTerm/termVocabulary)]
            ">
             <xsl:variable name="vRow3" select=
               "concat($vRow2, $vQ, ., $vQ, ';')"/>

            <xsl:for-each select=
             "$vTerm/relation/termVocabulary
             |
              $vDefaults/termCat[not($vTerm/relation/termVocabulary)]
             ">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($vRow3, $vQ, ., $vQ, ';')"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre Novatchev. It works fine when there is atleast one termCategory/termVocabulary/relation. But, when any one of tag is not there, (eg: no vocabulary tag, 2 category tags, 1 relation) we are not getting any row for the entire term. For the above term I would have to get 2 rows with an empty string in place of termVocabulary.

Comment: @user1147759: I have updated my solution to implement your new requirement.

Comment: Still, I am getting no rows for a term like:
      <term>
        <termId>49555</termId>
        <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
        <termName>Active Personnel</termName>
        <termCategory>PDI Term1</termCategory>
        <termCategory>GLB Term1</termCategory>
        <relation weight="100">
          <termId>49556</termId>
          <relationType>EQ Term1</relationType>
          <termName>term name Term1</termName>
          <termVocabulary>term vocabulary Term1</termVocabulary>
        </relation>
      </term>
where I should get 2 rows with "" for voc

Comment: Please, edit and update the question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: sorry, it was failing with 'Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it.' error. How should I enable it or can we have xsl without document()?

Comment: @user1147759: Then do what the message says -- enable the `document()` function.

Comment: works like a charm, except I need to append a header row and a footer row. For what I appended <br/> <xsl:text>"HDR";"Text";"20120112045620";"F"</xsl:text><br/> after <br/><xsl:template match="term"><br/> and <br/><xsl:text>"FTR";</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="count(term)" /><br/> above <br/></xsl:template><br/>. But these rows are getting apended for each term.

Comment: @user1147759: Please, accept this answer. Ask a new question for your new problem.

Comment: Accepted. :) please don't mind, new question would require to repost entire content. Please help me to append the header and footer.

Comment: @user: At least edit your current question -- I don't want to post an answer that produces something different than what the question asks for.

Comment: Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @user1147759: Reflected in my answer.

Comment: Works perfect. But, the number of rows in  output flat file  as part of the footer is missing. It cannot be count(term) as each term can result in more than 1 row in flat file. How can I get the total number of rows?

Comment: @user1147759: Do understand that you cannot ask a thousand after-questions.

Comment: really sorry, above is the last question.

Comment: Really sorry -- ask a new question.

Comment: here is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900133/number-of-rows-in-a-flat-file-transformed-from-xml-using-xslt