# Count number of rows in XSLT1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need some help on the XSLT please.

I got an XML file and I need to report some data twice in the file and soem data need to be filtered out.

and on the footer I need to report exactly how many rows are in the file.

Can someone please help me here?Thanks

Here is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<ns0:File xmlns:ns0="file">

  <ns0:Records>
    <ns0:Main>
      <ns0:Info>
        <ns0:InternalCode>1</ns0:InternalCode>
        <ns0:Name>test1</ns0:Name>
        <ns0:Factor>2.000000000000</ns0:Factor>
        <ns0:Type>a</ns0:Type>
      </ns0:Info>
    </ns0:Main>
<ns0:Main>
      <ns0:Info>
        <ns0:InternalCode>2</ns0:InternalCode>
        <ns0:Name>test2</ns0:Name>
        <ns0:Factor>10.000000000000</ns0:Factor>
        <ns0:Type>c</ns0:Type>
      </ns0:Info>
    </ns0:Main>
<ns0:Main>
      <ns0:Info>
        <ns0:InternalCode>3</ns0:InternalCode>
        <ns0:Name>test3</ns0:Name>
        <ns0:Factor>13.000000000000</ns0:Factor>
        <ns0:Type>b</ns0:Type>
      </ns0:Info>
    </ns0:Main>
<ns0:Main>
      <ns0:Info>
        <ns0:InternalCode>4</ns0:InternalCode>
        <ns0:Name>test4</ns0:Name>
        <ns0:Factor>1.000000000000</ns0:Factor>
        <ns0:Type>a</ns0:Type>
      </ns0:Info>
    </ns0:Main>
<ns0:Main>
      <ns0:Info>
        <ns0:InternalCode>5</ns0:InternalCode>
        <ns0:Name>test5</ns0:Name>
        <ns0:Factor>1.000000000000</ns0:Factor>
        <ns0:Type>f</ns0:Type>
      </ns0:Info>
    </ns0:Main>
    </ns0:Records>

  <ns0:Footer>
    <ns0:Time>10:54:40</ns0:Time>
    <ns0:NumberOfRecords>5</ns0:NumberOfRecords>
  </ns0:Footer>

</ns0:File>
```

And here is my XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="file">

      <xsl:output method="text"
         encoding="ASCII"/>

      <xsl:template match="ns0:Main">

<xsl:variable name="substractone">
      <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Info/ns0:Factor-1"/>
    </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test=" ns0:Factor !=0 and ns0:Type !='c' and $substractone !=0 ">


          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ns0:Type = 'a'">

              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:InternalCode"/>
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Name"/>
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Factor"/>
                        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    <!-- repeat in a new line -->
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:InternalCode"/>

              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Name"/>
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Factor"/>
                        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>

            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>


              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:InternalCode"/>

              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Name"/>
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Factor"/>
                        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>


        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="ns0:Footer">
        <!--Footer row-->
        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>*</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns0:NumberOfRecords"/>



        <!--record total-->


        <xsl:apply-templates/>

      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see the ns0:NumberOfRecords would have returned 5 here but in fact this file got 4 rows (filtering out type=c and 2 rows for each type=a)

Can someone please tell me how I can get the number of rows in the file correctly?

Comment: You obviously looked at my answer (since you corrected errors in your code that I point out). Would you mind telling me whether it solved your problem? By the way, please accept one of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743828/how-to-do-square-root-in-xslt-1-0

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see the ns0:NumberOfRecords would have returned 5 here but in fact this file got 6 rows (filtering out type=c and 2 rows for each type=a)

Instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="ns0:NumberOfRecords"/>
```

write

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//ns0:Type[. != 'c']) + count(//ns0:Type[. = 'a'])"/>
```

Then, you get the following output:

```
*6
```

---

Other issues with your XML and code:

- none of your `xsl:if` and `xsl:choose` evaluates to "true". Thus, the only thing that is output is the total number of records. This is because of the *context*.

By context I mean the following. Your template matches `ns0:Main` elements and that is therefore "your" position in the tree. Now, a line like this one:

```
<xsl:if test=" ns0:Factor !=0 and ns0:Type !='c' ">
```

actually looks for `ns0:Factor` and `ns0:Type` elements that are *immediate* children of the `ns0:Main` element. But, as you know, there are no such elements. Instead, `ns0:Factor` and `ns0:Type` are children of `ns0:Info`. You have to account for this fact:

```
<xsl:if test=" ns0:Info/ns0:Factor !=0 and ns0:Info/ns0:Type !='c' ">
```

Or perhaps it might be easier to change the template match:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:Main/ns0:Info">
```

If you make either of those changes, the output is:

```
1,test1,1.000000000000
1,test1,1.000000000000
3,test3,13.000000000000
4,test4,1.000000000000
4,test4,1.000000000000
5,test5,1.000000000000

*6
```

- you do not declare the XSLT namespace (`xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform")`in your stylesheet
- in your input XML, there is a surplus `</ns0:Records>` element that closes prematurely and prevents the file from being well-formed

Comment: thanks a lot mate. however this is just simplified examples I have have some extra filters based on the variable declared under the ns0:Main . I would need to declare them again under the ns0:Footer again right? but I don't think re-delacre them will work on the footer as each variable would need the data in the ns0:Main for each entry

Comment: For your future questions, when simplifying your XML data, make sure you only eliminate matter that does not contribute to your problem. There is no such thing as a "filter" in XSLT. What do you mean by that? It is impossible to say whether your approach is "right" without seeing the actual stylesheet.

Comment: or maybe i can declare the footerwithin the Main but how cna I just make it appear once??

Comment: If you meant reuse of variables, in general, the scope of variables is limited to where in the code they occur. They can be top-level elements (which makes them global) or inside `xsl:template` (can be used only inside this template) or inside `xsl:for-each` (can be used only inside this loop).

Comment: I really do not know what you are talking about. The footer template is triggered exactly once. You get its output (`*6`) exactly once.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mathias, I updated my XML and XSLT to included one variable in the IF statement.

Comment: This does not change anything I said. The `xsl:if` will always evaluate to false. Did you read my answer?

Comment: it does chaneg your answer. the extra condition makes your count incomplete there fore giving the wrong number <xsl:value-of select="count(//ns0:Type[. != 'c']) + count(//ns0:Type[. = 'a'])"/>

Comment: If this pointless variable means that the total number of rows should change, you'd have to tell me of course (or say so in the first place, i.e. what the exact conditions are for a row to be counted or not). This is the last time I am willing to make changes to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I foudn this post which does what I am after    <xsl:value-of select=
       "string-length($vMainOutput)
      -
        string-length(translate($vMainOutput, '&#xA;',''))
       "/>

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found this [Number of rows in a flat file transformed from xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900133/number-of-rows-in-a-flat-file-transformed-from-xml-using-xslt)

this will count the no. of line breaks and tell you how many rows are in the file: